# How mirror another line in Yasnippet?

Tags: yasnippet

I have the following snippet

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------
* METHOD ${1:$$(upcase yas-text)}.
* ---------------------------------------------------- */
public function f$1($2) {
    $3
}
```

My problem is that the mirror starts on `METHOD`, instead on `public
function`. So the upcase characters inside the function name, that I type in
`METHOD` will not being mirrored to the line with `public function`.

How could I configure the snippet to type on the line with `public function`,
while being mirrored in the line with `METHOD`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$$()` indicates a field transformation, not a mirror. To get a mirror use only 1 `$`:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------
* METHOD ${1:$(upcase yas-text)}.
* ---------------------------------------------------- */
public function f$1($2) {
    $3
}
```

http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-7

Comment: I swear, I have read the Yasnippet documentation closely but I couldn't find any reference to inverted miirror. From which I understood, Yasnippet counts the numbers top-down. Hence my question. I'm surprised it got working. Thank you npostavs! I appreciate it!

Comment: Both the documentation describing and code parsing the snippet syntax are in need of improvement. And probably the syntax itself should be improved (it's a bit hard to tell because there is no concise summary of it).

Comment: The documentation is good, but it could be more clear on some points, I agree with you.

Comment: `http://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-7`

is now

`http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-7`

Comment: You're fast! :)